# Remove incorrectly written URL from git remote push URL

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have got this situation:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@gits-15.sys.kth.se:/gruprog-20/hansji-p-uppgift.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/kulkarninomizuproduct/p-uppgift.git
  Push  URL: ^C
  Push  URL: ^C
  Push  URL: git@gits-15.sys.kth.se:/gruprog-20/hansji-p-uppgift.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

This happened when i tried to copy some things, and the "^C" got accidently added as a push URL to my remote called "origin" when i pressed ctrl+C (though I never pressed enter). I have tried many different commands to remove it:

```
$ git remote remove ^C
$ git remote rm ^C
$ git remote rm url ^C
$ git remote set-url --delete --push ^C
$ git remote set-url --delete ^C
$ git remote set-url --delete --push <^C>
$ git remote set-url --delete --push origin ^C
```

I suspect that the URL isnt actually "^C" but the actual command ctrl+C because look at this difference:

```
#When I write "git remote rm", then ctrl+C (as above, I dont need to press enter)(it returns nothing):

$ git remote rm ^C


# When I write "git remote ^C"

$ git remote rm ^C
fatal: No such remote: '^C'
```

Comment: If nothing else works, then all of this is stored inside `.git/config`, which is a normal text file. Make sure you edit it with a editor that understands linux conventions for line endings though (I believe).

Comment: Thank you! I removed it with a texteditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the remote you want to remove, so `origin` in this case, like so:

```
git remote remove origin
```

You can also use `set-url` to change the remote URL (change URL for actual origin git/https URL):

```
git remote set-url origin URL
```

If both of those aren't working for you, you can manually edit the following file from the root of the project:

```
.git/config
```

Which should have the contents like so:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ...
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Doesn't `git remote remove origin` remove the whole remote thats named origin? My fetch URL and two push URLs are correct, i only want to remove the "^C".

I dont want to change the "^C" to anything, because then i would have four push URLs? I only want two.

Comment: If would yes, apologies. But you could remove and add them again. I'd just manually edit the .git/config file then, and remove those lines if you don't want to change them :)

Comment: Ah, it was easy, i opened the config file with pychram and simply removed it. Thank you very much.